# How to get path for child in Array[String] returned by Jayway

Tags: java, scala, jsonpath, jsonparser, jayway

I have nested json data, like so:

```
{
  "libraries":[
    {
      "State":"California",
      "genres":[
          {
            "genre":"thriller",
            "books":[
              {
                "title":"Book 1"
              },
              {
                "title":"Book 2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "genre":"mystery",
            "books":[
              {
                "title":"Book 2"
              },
              {
                "title":"Book 3"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
    },
    {
      "State":"New York",
      "genres":[
          {
            "genre":"horror",
            "books":[
              {
                "title":"Book 2"
              },
              {
                "title":"Book 5"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "genre":"comedy",
            "books":[
              {
                "title":"Book 6"
              },
              {
                "title":"Book 7"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am using the jayway jsonpath library in Scala to parse it.
I could use something like `JsonPath.read(myData,"$.libraries[*].genres[*].books[*]")` to get an array of all the books pooled from every library. What I want is to know the path for each book, e.g. `"$.libraries(0).genres(1).books(0)"`. Is there a ways to get an array of all the book paths rather than just all the books?

I am new to jsonpaths in general, so forgive me if this is not a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use configuration with [`Option.AS_PATH_LIST`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-vs-value):

```scala
  val conf = Configuration.builder.options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build
  val paths = JsonPath.parse(json, conf).read[JSONArray]("$.libraries[*].genres[*].books[*]")
  for(path <- paths.toArray){
    println(path.toString)
  }
```

Which gives in case of your example json:

```
$['libraries'][0]['genres'][0]['books'][0]
$['libraries'][0]['genres'][0]['books'][1]
$['libraries'][0]['genres'][1]['books'][0]
$['libraries'][0]['genres'][1]['books'][1]
$['libraries'][1]['genres'][0]['books'][0]
$['libraries'][1]['genres'][0]['books'][1]
$['libraries'][1]['genres'][1]['books'][0]
$['libraries'][1]['genres'][1]['books'][1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted!